# Retornar ao menu

Tags: portugol

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade e estou tento uma dificuldade em por em prática minhas ideias.

O trabalho consiste em um "gerenciador para aluguel de carro".

Meu código até o momento esta assim:

```
  Algoritmo "semnome"

Var

   Cliente, endereco: vetor[1..5] de caractere
   RG, CPF, nas, CNH: vetor[1..5] de inteiro
   codigo, i: inteiro

procedimento cliente
inicio
   para i <- 1 ate 5 faca
      Escreval("Nome do cliente")
      Leia (Cliente[i])
      Escreval("RG")
      leia(RG[i])
      Escreval("CPF (Apenas numeros)")
      leia(cpf[i])
      Escreval("Endereço")
      Leia(endereco[i])
      Escreval("Data de nascimento")
      Leia(nas[i])
      Escreval("Numero da carteira de habilitaçao")
      leia(CNH[i])
      Escreval("o usuario ",(Cliente[i]), " foi cadastrado com sucesso!")
      Escreval("Gostaria de cadastrar outro cliente ?[S/N] ")
   fimpara
fimprocedimento

Inicio
   escreval("          Selecione uma opcao para continuar"          )
   escreval("-------------------------------------------------------")
   escreval("1 - Cadastro de cliente")
   Escreval("2 - Cadastro de automovel")
   escreval("3 - Classificacao de automoveis")
   escreval("4 - Movimentacao de locaçao")
   Escreval("5 - Sair")
   escreval("-------------------------------------------------------")
   leia (codigo)

   Escolha (codigo)
   caso 1
      cliente
Fimalgoritmo
```

Porém, no procedimento cliente. Eu gostaria de dar a opção de para quando quiser, não necessariamente ser 5 cadastros obrigatórios.

E após o cadastro voltar ao menu para selecionar outra opção.

Comment: Eu usaria uma máquina de estados. É uma modelagem adequada para o seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Bom primeiramente a sintaxe aí no fim está faltando um `fimescolha`.
Tente ver o exemplo abaixo e adicione ao código o repita para poder voltar ao menu para selecionar outra opção.

```
    Inicio
    escreval("          Selecione uma opcao para continuar"          )
    escreval("-------------------------------------------------------")
    escreval("1 - Cadastro de cliente")
    escreval("2 - Cadastro de automovel")
    escreval("3 - Classificacao de automoveis")
    escreval("4 - Movimentacao de locaçao")
    escreval("5 - Sair")
    escreval("-------------------------------------------------------")
    repita
    leia (codigo)
    escolha (codigo)
    caso 1
    cliente
    ate(codigo=5)
    fimescolha
    fimalgoritmo
```